# Does Source Based Linux Distro's Have Lower Download Size for Packages Rather Than Binary?

Tags: linux

I looked all over the internet and couldn't find the answer to my question. If you use a source based distro, does that lower download sizes, compared to binary? If so, how significant is it? (Provide an example if you could).

I have slow internet and I would like to cut downloading time and rather use that time to compile.

Thanks.

Comment: Binary packages are smaller than source packages, everyone knows that.

Comment: @ЯрославРахматуллин everyone must learn it once to then know it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you ask has a catch you seem to ignore: You can not boot a source file.

The core (installer, kernel, C compiler, other essential programs) will need to be downloaded as binaries. Additional package can be either pre-compiled or as source.

The best goal to minimize downloading would be to only download what you need. Start with a minimal installation set. Then decide which programs you want to add and how you want to manage them.  Either via download as source (e.g. via a BSD [ports tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ports_collection) or via Gentoo [portage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portage_%28software%29)) or a pre-compiled binary. The last preferably in a package format such as [rpm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RPM_Package_Manager) so you can not just install your system, but also keep it up to date without significant overhead.

As for an example: Those depend a lot on which examples you choose. The only fair comparison would be from a full system install (with average used programs) and to compare those. And then we need to start a discussion (with no clear answers) on what average installed programs are.